# Espresso should not wait for async task to finish. How?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-espresso

I have an android application where **Activity A on click starts a thread**. I need this thread to be running for some time (2-3 minutes), but I also can navigate to other fragments and activities during this time.

Manually the application does not have any problem. But with espresso automation tests I do. I am trying to do the process where the Thread starts (does not die soon), but I navigate to other activities with mocked click by espresso. I always get the error that espresso is waiting and the ASYNC_TASK is not idle.

**I need to espresso to over-look this and navigate to other screens. Is there a way to do this ?**

Comment: Try to execute the AsyncTask against a custom Executor as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398781/how-can-i-make-espresso-test-continue-and-not-wait-for-an-asynctask-to-complete/56543179#56543179)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), in which you can do as heavy job as you want, and everything will be in the background, not just leaving the UI thread free, but also you can move between activities as long as you want.

This is a sample code, [a full example is avaiable as well](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

```
public class HeavyJobExecutor extends IntentService {


    public HeavyJobExecutor() {
        super("WhateverNameYouWant");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        for (int i = 0 ;i < 100; i ++) {
            try {
                new URL("http://stackoverflow.com").openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to read also about [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), because you can use them to check the status of your intent service.

Comment: But, I already have the HeavyJobExecutor running on an async task in the background. 
My problem is Espresso waits for this to finish, which I don't want.

Comment: I am not sure if going with espresso was the right option for this. I started using UIAutomator that works at device level which does not care about the application thread. This was the work-around that worked for me

Comment: Great happy coding